# htaccess - redirect query string and remove it

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I search many topic about htaccess but still not success.

I want when people type address:

```
http://domain.com/download.php?q=filename1
http://domain.com/download.php?q=filename2
```

It will auto redirect to:

```
http://domain.com/download/filename1.html
http://domain.com/download/filename2.html
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^download\.php download/%1.html? [R=301,L]
```